# Build.gradle error in flutter project: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, build.gradle

I am getting this message when trying to run my flutter project:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\kalen\Documents\Development\projects\Good Vibes\shop_app\good_vibes_shop_app\android\app\build.gradle' line: 28
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> No signature of method: build_e36rplgrfp57e9uvkfg0oc8u0.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_e36rplgrfp57e9uvkfg0oc8u0$_run_closure2) values: [build_e36rplgrfp57e9uvkfg0oc8u0$_run_closure2@46a9b49]

*Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

Here is my build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    compileSdkVersion 33
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.good_vibes_shop_app"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            useProguard true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro' 
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
repositories {
   google()
   maven {
     url 'https://sdk.squareup.com/public/android'
   }
 }

dependencies {
  implementation "com.squareup.sdk.in-app-payments:card-entry:4.2.0"
}
```

I am trying to add square in-app payment to my app and it's my first time doing anything like this at all. Hopefully somebody out there with some fresh and experienced eyes can help.

I'm not really experienced enough to be able to describe what I did. I tried running `./gradlew clean` in the terminal and that didn't help anything. I also made sure that I was upgraded to mavenCentral. It sort of just started throwing me an error all of a sudden.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the actual issue is with the last line of the build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
  implementation "com.squareup.sdk.in-app-payments:card-entry:4.2.0"
}
```

This line is not placed inside any android block. To fix this error, you can move this line into the dependencies block above, right after the line implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version".

After the fix, the build.gradle file will maybe look like this:

```
...
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.sdk.in-app-payments:card-entry:4.2.0"
}
repositories {
    google()
    maven {
        url 'https://sdk.squareup.com/public/android'
    }
}
...
```

By moving the line implementation "com.squareup.sdk.in-app-payments:card-entry:4.2.0" to the correct position within the dependencies block, you should no longer encounter the "No signature of method" error.

Comment: I tried adding the implementation into the dependencies block, and that did not work. I made sure that it was all added to the android block, but I am still receiving the same error.